# Load Users into jQuery during onLoad of a page for a Live Search

Tags: jquery

All,
I've got the following code to which is basically a function that loads some search terms in it when the DOM is loading:

```
window.myAutocompleteFunction = function(){
return ['Test Saying','sit amet consectetur adipiscing','elit Nulla et justo'];
};
```

This works fine for my live search and updates correctly. I'm trying to populate these values based on some information from my database though. I tried to update my code to use a .get function to populate my return values and I tried to make it look like this:

```
window.myAutocompleteFunction = function(){
$.get('http://localhost/website/load_users.php', function(data) {
    alert(data);
    return [data];
});
};
```

It tries to load the users and in my alert it is the same as when it's manually typed in but for some reason when I do the search it doesn't work. Any idea how to get the same results from my file and have the search work the same?

**EDIT:** The only thing in my load_users.php file right now is the following:

```
'Test Saying','sit amet consectetur adipiscing','elit Nulla et justo'
```

I'm going to try and populate that with database values but just trying to get this to work for now.

**Another Edit:** I also tried to make my code like the following just to see if it work work:

```
window.myAutocompleteFunction = function(){
jQuery.get('http://localhost/okyne/load_users.php', function(data) {
    alert(data);
    return ['Test Saying','sit amet consectetur adipiscing','elit Nulla et justo'];
});
};
```

This doesn't work either so I'm not sure why it wouldn't work and the only thing that works for me so far is the first code snippet that I provided.

Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you've included jquery properly? It looks like $ does not equal jQuery().

Comment: @Erica I changed it to jQuery instead of $ and now it hits the get but still doesn't work on the live search to return the results of the get.

Comment: I also updated my question for the specific issue now.

Comment: Your question title is misleading. The problem isn't that jQuery isn't being loaded, it sounds like you've already included that.

Comment: @nbrooks I updated my question title. Good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$.get` can't return a value like that, because it runs asynchronously and the browser starts evaluating it, moves on and finishes with that fn. before it completes. *Also*, that particular `return` will target the inner success-callback function, not the autocomplete function. You will have to load the data and create that function in the success callback.

Here is a mockup example. http://jsfiddle.net/Nf2UD/

Note I used setTimeout to make sure the ajax call was finished, but you will want to ensure you call randomFn during your page initialization, to ensure it has run before you try and use autocomplete. You can check this in a couple ways -- having a global variable to track the status, checking if the autocomplete function is undefined, .... In truth this isn't really the point of asynchronous methods, but whatever works for you I guess.

```
function() randomFn {
    $.get('http://localhost/website/load_users.php', function(data) {
        alert(data);
        window.myAutocompleteFunction = function(){ return [data]; };
    });
};
```

Comment: That does get me the results so thank you! However, one issue remains. It considers the results as a single entry instead of showing up on three different line items like how it would in my first code snippet. Any ideas why that would be?

Comment: Nevermind, I moved the brackets into my PHP file and now it works good! Thanks!

Comment: p.s. (maybe for future ref.) that means it was treating it as a single string with commas in it. `var x = data.split(',');` would solve that. No problem, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    function getScript(url,success){
        var script=document.createElement('script');
        script.src=url;
        var head=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        done=false;
        script.onload=script.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if ( !done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete') ) {
        done=true;
        success();
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
        head.removeChild(script);
        }
        };
        head.appendChild(script);
    }

    getScript('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js',function(){

        /* YOUR CODE GOES HERE AND IS EXECUTED AFTER JQUERY LOADS */

    });
```

Comment: I updated my question. The jQuery loads fine. My issue is more with populating jQuery with some values to use for live search.